# Copy Text from SMS pulls wrong text

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, copy-paste

On my ICS 4.0.4 Nexus S when I go to a message that I've just sent to a person and select it, then 'Copy Text' and somewhere else 'Paste' the text it seems to pull the 4th/5th message above the one I've selected. However it only does this behaviour 2 out of every 3 times or so, I can't reproduce it at will. Is there a fix for this and/or is it a known issue?